# Setting a buffer around a road and visualizing it in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

So i need to set a 30 meter Buffer around a road in a Layer and visualize it in QGIS. The road is split in 8 segments( don´t think it makes a difference).

Tried this code:

```
select a.ref, a.geom, st_buffer(a.geom, 30)
from au.roads a
where a.ref='A306'
```

When i load it in QGIS it doesn´t show a Buffer around that road. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your query is returning **two** geometries ... that must must distract QGIS i suppose ... try to only keep your buffer's geometry ...

Comment: Where did u try _'this code'_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query create two geometries, 
so you need to tell Qgis what is your geometry column when you load your table
(or either don't select a.geom)

when you load a table with two geometry column in postgreSQL loader it give you this (exemple from one of my project) :

[image]

here, you can either load the table with geom as the geometry column or border as the geom column.